Is it possible that SELECT query is blocking nodes synchronization in Always On?
I encountered a peculiar situation. We have an Always On setup (SQL Server 2019) with two replicas: a master replica and a secondary replica. On the secondary replica, there was a SELECT query that ran for 19 hours. After executing whoisactive, discovered that this SELECT session had been blocking the Always On synchronization for 6 hours. Is it possible for a SELECT query to acquire an LCK_M_SCH_M lock and impede synchronization?



Is it possible for a SELECT query to acquire an LCK_M_SCH_M lock and impede synchronization?

No, and yes.
A select query will not be able to directly affect synchronization which is typically considered to be the process of hardening log data onto the secondary replica. It can indirectly affect it but would require a series of unfortunate events to fully enact... however, what you've provided has nothing to do with synchronization or "lag" in data transport and hardening, but with the REDO of the data which has been synchronized.
Secondary replicas which are marked readable must still follow the same locking semantics as a primary. Thus, when attempting to redo a change on a data page, locks will need to be taken. If those locks are incompatible with anything that is currently running then it'll be blocked. Note that this is REDO that is blocked, which has an associated redo lock blocked extended event.
The SELECT query didn't acquire a schema modification lock but does require a schema stability lock. Redo is waiting to acquire the schema modification lock to redo some operation originally executed on the primary. But it is being blocked by the SELECT query since the locks of a SELECT query are incompatible with schema modification locks, regardless of the fact that AlwaysOn Availability Groups transparently use optimistic concurrency (Snapshot Isolation). So the REDO in that specific database has to wait for the SELECT query to finish, so that it can make the schema modification in a stable way.
SQLSkills info on the LCK_M_SCH_M Wait Type:

This wait type is when a thread is waiting to acquire a Schema Modification (also called Schema Modify) lock on a resource and there is at least one other lock in an incompatible mode granted on the resource to a different thread.

Also, see this less than pretty lock compatibility matrix from the Microsoft docs for further reference:


So it probably means that on master replica it was some DDL change or index rebuild and because of that it was a lag on secondary replica (due to long select) ?

@adam.g Correct! Something changed on the primary replica that required a schema modification lock (e.g. some sort of DDL query ran), and on the secondary replica when it went to apply that change, it can't do so in a stable way until the SELECT query is done running. By the way, I updated my answer with a little more information, for reference.
